# CSS: Inline Div with auto width pushes down when the text is long

Tags: html, css

I'm facing a css problem realted to inline-div.
When the text(or sentece) is long, the inline div pushes down as on the image below:[image]

But, when I add a line break, It works perfectly.[image]

How can I make it work without having to use `<br>`? 
The main content to be posted is dynamic and it also needs to be responsive.
Thanks

> Please Note: This is a simplified version of my actual code. In the
>   actual code the width of the main container is 100%

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div id="firstDiv">FIRST</div>
<div id="secondDiv">SECOND</div>
<div id="thirdDiv">THIRD
<br>some more content<br> some more content
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
    width: 350px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#container {
    border: 15px solid orange;   
}
#firstDiv{
    border: 10px solid brown;     
    display:inline-block;
    width: 70px;      
    overflow:hidden; 
    vertical-align:top;
}
#secondDiv{
    border: 10px solid skyblue;         
    float:left;
    width: 70px;     
}
#thirdDiv{
    display:inline-block;
    border: 5px solid yellowgreen; 
    vertical-align:top;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use : `white-space: nowrap;` for the div containing the long sentences.

Comment: Hey. Thanks but its not working. Overflow is occuring when I use it.

Comment: try playing with the `white-space` property (normal, nowrap, pre, pre-line, pre-wrap, initial, inherit), i think what you're looking for is `wihte-space:pre;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox. Just add

```
#container { 
  display: flex;
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  border: 15px solid orange;
}

#firstDiv {
  border: 10px solid brown;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#secondDiv {
  border: 10px solid skyblue;
  float: left;
  width: 70px;
}

#thirdDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid yellowgreen;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="firstDiv">FIRST</div>
  <div id="secondDiv">SECOND</div>
  <div id="thirdDiv">THIRD
    <br>some more content<br> some more content
  </div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. My main container is 100%. When I use flex, overflow occures on the width.